# loading php pages with out .php extension

Tags: php, apache2

I'm new to php and I have created a simple site using php5. my question is

I have a page called login.php , when I type http:///login.php, the page loads

But what I want to do is to load the page without giving the .php extension , as follows

http:///login

Can I do like this, I'm running on apache2 and hoping to publish my site in a shared environment

thanks in advance

cheers
sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` file in root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not going to work if there is more than one period in the filename.